# Comparing versons of an item when using data source items

Tags: content-editor, versions

We're a bit behind the curve in adopting this stuff, but I hope that makes this an easier question. I should also mention we are on 7.2

Historically we had published articles on our site where, through template inheritance, the published item had a field for each element on the page (single line, rich text, images etc.).

We have thousands of articles and it's typical for an article to go through a couple of versions, both initially in the copy editing process and going forward as edits are made to keep the content evergreen.  For these old-style items, our content editors found it easy to compare versions of the article because the built-in version compare tool showed changes to each field on one screen.

Subsequently, we have been building new pages following the Helix pattern where we are composing the article out of components, each of which may use a `common/shared or local (under ./Data ) data source item`, and enjoying all the benefits of that approach, except we have lost the ability to compare versions of an article.

To be clear, the compare version tool still does what it should - however, the edits that need to be compared now belong to versions of the data source items.

We have looked at using the built-in version compare tool to explore the history of the data source item, which again works as designed but does not meet our needs in that

1. it's sub-optimal to have to compare versions on each data source item
2. This approach doesn't give visibility to the edits in context.  For example, a revision may swap out two images, update some text and rephrase a heading.  Comparing the history of several data source items is not the same as comparing the whole change if that makes sense,

Has anyone found a solution to this whereby editors could visually see edits to a page over time by comparing versions of the data source items?